# Image of diagonal map in prevarieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Suppose $X$ is a prevariety as in the definition of Mumford in the Red Book of Varieties and Schemes (that is, a space with functions locally isomorphic to an affine variety). Consider the map $\Delta: X \to X \times X$ defined by $\Delta = (id_X, id_X)$, where $id_X$ is the identity map of $X$. In the book, Mumford says that $\Delta(X) = \{ z \in X \times X: p_1(z) = p_2(z)\}$, where $p_1,p_2$ are the projection maps. However, I don't know how to prove that the latter set is indeed the image of $\Delta$. I know that $\Delta$ is a monomorphism, and that the image of $\Delta$ is contained in $\{z \in X \times X:  p_1(z) = p_2(z)\}$, because $p_1 \circ \Delta = p_2 \circ \Delta = id_X$. I can't prove the converse inclusion, however. My guess is that $\Delta(p_1(z)) = z$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

I call $Z=\{z\in X\times X\mid pr_1(z)=pr_2(z)\}$ and let $j:Z\hookrightarrow X\times X$ be the relevant inclusion.

Trivially $pr_1\circ j=pr_2\circ j\equiv\varphi:Z\to X$ and easily one proves the injectivity of $\varphi$. By definition $\Delta\circ\varphi=\left(Id_X,Id_X\right)\circ pr_k\circ j$, with $k\in\{1,2\}$, and
$$
\forall z\in Z,\,\Delta\circ\varphi(z)=(pr_k(z),pr_k(z))\in Z;
$$
then the image of $\Delta$ is contained in $Z$.

Vice versa:
\begin{gather*}
\forall z\in Z,\,\Delta^{-1}(z)=\left(Id_X,Id_X\right)^{-1}(z)=\\
=\{x\in X\mid\left(Id_X,Id_X\right)(x)=(x,x)=z\}=\{pr_1(z)=pr_2(z)\in X\}\neq\emptyset;
\end{gather*}
in other words: $\Delta$ is onto $Z$.

By the previous part one has the equality of these sets.

Comment: I need to prove that Z is contained in the image, correct?

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding; I edited and completed my answer.